Confused about wheel size 700X35 vs 622X19
I need a new front wheel for my bike. The imprint on the wheel says 622x19, which from my understanding is the diameter and the width of the rim. Looking for a new one, I found this one:
Wheel Masters Wheel Front 700X35 622X19 Wei Zac19 Sl 36 Aly Qr Sl 12Gss
I understand that the 700 refers to the same diameter in a different system but I am confused by the 35 behind it.
Thanks for your help!

Welcome to the site!   Side question - what's wrong with the old wheel that you need a complete replacement ?

Thank you! The answer is embarrassing…I didn’t notice that the brake shoes were so worn out that pieces of the metal fitting were pushed against the rim every time I used the brake. At some point you could hear that something is wrong but the rim was already damaged…

If only the rim is damaged you might be able to only replace the rim, in which case the number of spoke holes is important. You can do that replacement yourself or have it done.

Unfortunately re-building can be time consuming and expensive. For cheap wheels it’s often cheaper to buy a whole new wheel. Donate the hubs and spokes to your local bike shop or co-op.

Bicycle tyres and wheels are cursed by having many different methods for measurement.
700 is an old value that doesn't describe a physical dimension, but means the same as 622.   It is from the French system, and 700mm was about the diameter of the whole wheel-and-tyre when inflated, so it depends on the tyre and air pressure too.
622mm is the "Bead Seat Diameter" of the wheel, basically where in the rim the bead of the tyre rests.  622 is standard for "road bikes"
35 in this example probably means 35mm external width of the tyre when installed.  Though this seems a higher value than I'd expect given:
19 means the internal width of the rim is 19mm
Wei, Zac19, and Sl mean nothing to me.   However Zac19 was a model for a Weinmann rim.  Could be this wheel is built with a Weinmann Zac19 rim or its just some text thrown in to confuse search engines.
36 is possibly the spoke hole count.  This has to match exactly the number of spoke holes in your hub.  36 would be a lot for a front wheel, where 32 and 28 would be more common.  36 is more often found on a rear wheel, though nothing says you can't have 36 spoke front wheels.
Aly probably says its an Aluminium rim.
Qr suggests a Quick Release, though this is part of the hub's spec, not a rim.
Si for the second time still carries no meaning for me.
12Gss is probably 12 Gauge Stainless Steel spokes.

I now see you're looking at a replacement wheel, not a rim to fit to your existing hub/spokes.
One thing you haven't presented is the brakes.

If your bike is disk brakes then the wheel needs a place to mount a rotor on the hub.
If you have rim brakes then the rim needs a brake track machined around the rim.

You cannot and must-not use a rim designed for disk brakes only, under rim-brake calipers.  The opposite is acceptable - it is okay to use a rim with a rim-brake track on a disk brake bike assuming the rotor mount is present.

Thank you for the detailed answer! I double checked that the rim works with rim brakes :)

The Weinmann rim business has been sold a couple of times, and the Zac19 rims have been made under Rigida and now Ryde brands. According to DuckDuckGo there's also a Chinese company that calls itself Weinmann and sells Zac19 rims that don't seem to have anything to do with the European brands but could well be the rim in OP's listing.

We know from OP comments that this is for rim brakes - might be good to have that edited into the Q

622x19 on a rim states the rim diameter x the internal width in mms. The ETRTO system for tires states inner diameter x tire width in mms, e.g 622x37. This is all good and logical and "all you need to know".
Unfortunately there exists other systems of measurement, and for tires the french system is given by outer diameter(e.g 700mm) with a given tire width(e.g 35mm) and a letter(e.g C=622mm) to designate the internal diameter. This would then be a 700x35C tire. This latter system really isn't for rims as far as I know, and not stating a letter designating the inner width makes no sense at all for a rim/wheel.
https://www.schwalbetires.com/technology-faq/tire-sizes/
